# Installing Another linux OS

Tags: dual-boot, burg

I have Ubuntu with BURG was installed and I intended to install Backtrack to my computer. I'm afraid, if I install Backtrack, will it erase my Burg-loader. How to recover this BURG after installing Backtrack (Without re-downloading BURG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go ahead and install BackTrack. When you're done, boot to Ubuntu, and then execute this from the terminal:

```
sudo burg-install /dev/the_target_disk
```

Replace the_target_disk with the device name of the disk you want to reinstall Burg to. In most cases it is sda or hda, but yours can be different. After that, run this:

```
sudo update-burg
```

Good luck!